# Garbage collector is not running

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I understand that we cannot guarantee that garbage collector is called in java.

```
public class finalizeDemo {
    protected void finalize() {
        System.out.println("Wow!! I am called");
    }
}

class testFinalizeDemo {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        finalizeDemo obnj = new finalizeDemo();

        System.gc();
        /**
         *  Forcefully call garbage collector.
         */
    }
}
```

But I read that `System.gc()` will invoke gc forcefully. But my statement is not getting printed in my local eclipse.

Does anyone know why the statement isn't being printed?

Comment: If you understand that you can't guarantee that GC is called, how can you believethat System.gc() will invoke gc forcefully? Why don't you read it javadoc? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29. And why do you think anything should be GCed? You still have a reference to the object when calling gc(), so it can't be GCed.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the ref to doc. I dont see a line that it is not guaranteed. Thats what confused me. If it not guranteed, i don't understand the total purpose of this method?

Comment: If the javadoc said that the method *forces* the JVM to do a GC, then you would have a guarantee. But the javadoc doesn't say that. It says that the method **suggests** the JVM to do a GC.

Comment: Thanks Man :) I am just learning things by trying out. My reference book have a wrong message that it would be called forcefully

Comment: It’s also worth noting that a GC does not necessarily imply execution of finalizers. A GC might enqueue all objects needing finalization for later processing. Most objects don’t need special finalization…

Answer (score 0):

When you call System.gc the object referenced by obnj is a live object. It is still being referenced by the obnj. So the correct behaviour for the garbage collector is to NOT finalize de object.

Try adding obnj=null before the call to System.gc()

It is still not guaranteed that the object will be finalized but at least now it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The code will print

> Wow!! I am called

because there a reference tor the object that needs to finalize.

```
class FinalizeDemo {
     protected void finalize()
    {
      System.out.println("Wow!! I am called");
    }
  }

public class testFinalizeDemo
  {
    public static void main(String[] a)
    {
      FinalizeDemo obnj = new FinalizeDemo();
      obnj = null;

      System.gc();
      /**
       *  Forcefully call garbage collector.
       */
    }
  }
```